# SUM or Total results from Union ALL SQL

Tags: sql-server, sum, subtotal

Hi I have queries to display 2 results:

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 103) AS Date, 
       'Sales Orders' AS Type, COUNT(SalesOrderID) AS Qty, 
       ISNULL(ROUND(SUM(SubTotal), 2),0) AS [Total Ex GST]
FROM  dbo.SalesOrder
WHERE  (DateCreated > CONVERT(int, GETDATE()-0.5))

UNION ALL

SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 103) AS Date,
       'Invoices', COUNT(InvoiceID) AS Qty, 
       ISNULL(ROUND(SUM(SubTotal),2),0) AS [Total Ex GST]
FROM         dbo.Invoice
WHERE  (DateCreated > CONVERT(int, GETDATE()-0.5))
```

How would I add these 2 unions 55090.25 and 1522.8 to produce 3rd row? for TOTALS?

Comment: Can you show us the queries?

Comment: please edit your question to add it so that you can format it correclty and  other users will be able to see it

Comment: @LioraHaydont edited it :)

Comment: Why do you need a query to calculate the total? Can't you handle this on the application level?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos unfortunately not, so I need to show an automated report so once I see the results of these 2 values, on the third row, I can also see the sum of these 2 values :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 103) AS Date, 'Sales Orders' AS Type, COUNT(SalesOrderID) AS Qty, ISNULL(ROUND(SUM(SubTotal), 2),0) AS [Total Ex GST]
    FROM         dbo.SalesOrder
    WHERE     (DateCreated > CONVERT(int, GETDATE()-0.5))
    UNION
    SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 103) AS Date, 'Invoices', COUNT(InvoiceID) AS Qty, ISNULL(ROUND(SUM(SubTotal), 2),0) AS [Total Ex GST]
    FROM         dbo.Invoice
    WHERE     (DateCreated > CONVERT(int, GETDATE()-0.5)) 
),
TotalCTE AS
(
    SELECT CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 103) AS Date, 'Total' AS Type, SUM(Qty) AS Qty, SUM([Total Ex GST]) AS [Total Ex GST] FROM CTE
)
SELECT Date, [Type], Qty, [Total Ex GST] FROM CTE
UNION
SELECT Date, [Type], Qty, [Total Ex GST] FROM TotalCTE;
```

Here's a working Fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/eb9a0/2/0

Answer (score 0):

You query is producing the following result:

```
Date        Type          Qty  [Total Ex GST]
---------------------------------------------
2018-03-08  Sales Orders  100  55090.25  
2018-03-08  Invoices      200  1522.8
```

I've added some arbitrary `Qty` values for the sake of completeness.

You can wrap your query in a *Common table expression* and perform a `GROUP BY GROUPING SETS` on the result set of the `CTE`:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
   ... your query here ...
)
SELECT [Date], 
       COALESCE(Type, 'Both') AS Type, 
       SUM(Qty) AS Qty, 
       Sum(Total) AS Total
FROM CTE
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (([Date], Type),(Date))
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8cfd4/6)